# Update of List of Tables in Microsoft Word - Caption is two lines but I want both in the Table of Tables

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft

I have an issue in the list of Tables in Microsoft Word that when I update it, it catches only the item "Table 24" for e.g. without catching the whole caption which is "Table 24. Number of candies" since "Number of candies" is putten on a new line but still is considered in the caption ... how can I resolve this issue and get the whole caption in the List of Tables (without putting "Number of candies" on the same line as "Table 24")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try using a line break (Shift+Enter) to separate your two lines.

A Table of Tables / Figures, uses the same field as a Table of Contents with different switches. It follows the same rules.

See:

- [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [Creating a Table of Figures](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures) *(my writing)*

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have a problem that when I am inserting the cross reference it appears by default bold and italic ... do you have an idea how to make it appear like the text font by default?  I have tried to change the default caption font but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at the TOC Tips and Tricks. It looks to me like you have direct formatting applied in your captions that is then showing up in your TOT. For instance, if your Caption style is Bold and Italic and you directly format the caption to not have those features it will turn them on in your TOT. If that is not the case, then perhaps you applied Bold and Italics to the captions, rather than changing the style.

Comment: Thanks but I am not talking here about the TOC ... I am solely talking about the cross reference font that is appearing every time I put a cross reference like for e.g. "Table 24" within the text, it appears automatically bold and Italic but I want it to be normal like the text... how to do that?